# Can Pylance handle with new members in inherited classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, pylance

This minimal example:

```
from typing import List
class Base:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def do_something(self):
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylist: List[Base] = []
    mylist.append(Child())
    mylist.append(Child())

    for child in mylist:
        child.do_something()
```

brings Pylance to give me this error message:

```
do_something: Unknown
Cannot access member "do_something" for type "Base"
   Member "do_something" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues"
```

The reason of this message is clear to me, but as the program works correctly, I assume it is correct Python. So I want to know, if Pylance can deal with this situation or do I have to live with this error message.

Comment: If you intend to make use of `Child`-specific features of the elements of `mylist`, then it's type should be `List[Child]`. `List[Base]` says you can assume every element of the list will satisfy the API of `Base`, but `Base` does not define a `do_something` method.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but in my real program, I can't change the type of the list because its part of the Pygame library (pygame.sprite.Group). So the types are given and I want to know, if Pylance can handle it.

Comment: It is handling it. It's telling you are that you are invalidly assuming that elements of a list of type `List[Base]` have a method named `do_something`, because `Base.do_something` does not exist.

Comment: Your code only works because you haven't added anything except instances of `Child` to the list. Add `mylist.append(Base())` before the loop, and you'll see the error in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using features of `Child` that aren't part of the interface to `Base`, so `List[Base]` is the wrong type for `mylist`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mylist: List[Child] = []
    mylist.append(Child())
    mylist.append(Child())

    for child in mylist:
        child.do_something()
```

Not every subclass of `Base` would necessarily support a `do_something` method, so it would be legal to add instances of those subclass to a list of type `List[Base]`, but not work properly in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for yout hint. But, "List" is on purpose of "Base" and not "Child". The problem came up by using a pygame.sprite.Group object to manage Sprites objects. pygame.sprite.Group is defined as as a List of Sprites. My game object is a child class of Sprite with new members. So, if I iterate through the list and calls member of the child class, I get the pylance error.